# Conversion from NonStrictExceptions to Expectations

Tags: jmockit

I have test cases using `NonStrictExpectations` in jMockit v 1.22 as follows:

```
@Mocked Scanner mockScanner;

@Test
public void getNumber496() {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        mockScanner.nextLine(); result = "496";
    }};
    int val = PrimeOrPerfect.getNumber();  // calls Scanner.nextLine() for a number
    assertEquals(496, val);
}
```

The mocking works fine.

After upgrading to jMockit v. 1.25 I changed to `Expectations` (since `NonStrictExceptions` is deprecated) as shown below:

```
@Mocked Scanner mockScanner;

@Test
public void getNumber496() {
    new Expectations() {{
        mockScanner.nextLine(); result = "496";
    }};
    int val = PrimeOrPerfect.getNumber();  // calls Scanner.nextLine() for a number
    assertEquals(496, val);
}
```

The mocked method always returns **null**.  What's wrong with the new code?

Here is the code for getNumber():

```
protected static int getNumber() {
    logger.info(">>getNumber()");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean validInput = false;
    int number;
    System.out.println("Enter a whole positive number (0 to quit):");
    do {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        logger.info("input number: {}", line);
        number = 0;
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(line);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            logger.debug("input is invalid: {}", e.toString());
            System.err.println("Please enter a positive integer less than 1001.");
            continue;
        }
        if (number < 0 || number > 1000 ) {
            logger.debug("input is out of range 1..1000.");
            System.err.println("Please enter a valid number between 1 and 1,000 inclusive.");
        } else {
            validInput = true;
        }
    } while (!validInput);
    // Don't close the scanner because doing so also closes System.in.  Do NOT uncomment the line below.
    //scanner.close();
    logger.info("<<getNumber()");
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a more complete test, with the `PrimeOrPerfect` class? For me, the second test with `Expectations` works identically to the first one.

Comment: Rogerio, I have updated the posting as you requested.

Comment: I copied all the code to a JUnit test class, using JMockit 1.25, but the test runs fine; the call to `nextLine()` always returns `"496"`. So, I've no idea what happens on your side for it to return `null`.

Comment: Notice that a good alternative test with no mocking is to redirect standard input: `System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("496".getBytes()));`.

Comment: Rogerio, Must be an environmental problem.  I've tried with Eclipse Mars and Eclipse Neon and various levels of Java JDK at 1.8.x levels.  Can you describe your versions?

Comment: I use IntelliJ and various JDK versions (1.8 included). This problem doesn't make much sense, because `Expectations` is virtually identical to `NonStrictExpectations`; the *only* difference is the default value for the `minTimes` constraint.

Comment: I spent the afternoon investigating this again (environment Eclipse Neon, jMockit 1.25, OS X 10.10.5).  I thought one test case messed up the mockScanner so I moved it to another JUNIT test file.  Started working, however when I added the JVM arguments the same infinite loop resurfaced.

Put everything back together and it is the presence of these JVM args that triggers the infinite loop:

    -Djmockit-coverage-metrics=line,path
    -Djmockit-coverage-output=html

If the above source is insufficient I can email all files or even the Eclipse project itself.

Comment: @Rogério Above comment is probably bogus.  There is an interaction between mock Scanner and setting the input stream.  Still trying to diagnose.